# Crafting for faster WHERE querying on a UNION'd table?

Tags: mysql, sql

I am making a query who's data is used to build a tree navigator in our app (really I am remaking a old slow complex query in our code base).  There's 5 steps to the hierarchy, Customer -> Location -> Area -> Assets -> Area, and each of these tables have a column "active" which will be used for filtering purposes.

So, here's my question -  what is the better route to go with the active columns for filter?

Right now I have the table come back like this

```
path         text        type        active
''           customer1   customer    1
customer1    location1   location    1
customer1    location2   location    0
```

Such that if a user doesn't want to see inactive locations, I'd filter with a `WHERE type='location' AND active!=0`.  However, I was thinking maybe it'd be better to create an active column for every single level and just put in 1's for rows that aren't that specific type, like so

```
path         text        customerActive    locationActive   areaActive
''           customer1        1                  1               1
customer1    location1        1                  1               1
customer1    location2        1                  0               1
```

so that then if I wanted only active locations I'd do `WHERE locationActive = 1`.

Is one of these techniques faster or a better practice than the other?  Is there any consensus on situations like this?

Here's the current SQL code generating the first type of table

```
(SELECT 
    '' AS `path`,
        `listcustomers`.`name` AS `text`,
        'customer' AS `type`,
        `listcustomers`.`idx` AS `id`,
        `listcustomers`.`active` AS `active`,
        IF(`listcustomers`.`active`, 'tree/CustomerActive.png', 
'tree/CustomerInactive.png') AS `icon`
FROM
    `listcustomers`) UNION (SELECT 
    `listcustomers`.`name` AS `path`,
        `listlocations`.`name` AS `text`,
        'location' AS `type`,
        `listcustomers`.`idx` AS `id`,
        `listcustomers`.`active` AS `active`,
        IF(`listlocations`.`active`, 'tree/LocationActive.png', 
'tree/LocationInactive.png') AS `icon`
FROM
    `listlocations`
JOIN `listcustomers` ON `listcustomers`.`idx` = 
`listlocations`.`parentCustomerId`) UNION (SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS('/', `listcustomers`.`name`, `listlocations`.`name`),
        `listareas`.`name` AS `text`,
        'areas' AS `type`,
        `listareas`.`idx` AS `id`,
        `listareas`.`active` AS `active`,
        IF(`listareas`.`active`, 'tree/AreaActive.png', 
'tree/AreaInactive.png') AS `icon`
FROM
    `listareas`
JOIN `listlocations` ON `listlocations`.`idx` = 
`listareas`.`parentLocationId`
JOIN `listcustomers` ON `listcustomers`.`idx` = 
`listlocations`.`parentCustomerId`) UNION (SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS('/', `listcustomers`.`name`, `listlocations`.`name`, 
`listareas`.`name`) AS `path`,
        `listassets`.`name` AS `text`,
        'assets' AS `type`,
        `listassets`.`idx` AS `id`,
        `listassets`.`active` AS `active`,
        IF(`listassets`.`active`, 'tree/assetActive.png', 
'tree/assetInactive.png') AS `icon`
FROM
    `listassets`
JOIN `listareas` ON `listareas`.`idx` = `listassets`.`parentAreaId`
JOIN `listlocations` ON `listlocations`.`idx` = 
`listareas`.`parentLocationId`
JOIN `listcustomers` ON `listcustomers`.`idx` = 
`listlocations`.`parentCustomerId`) UNION (SELECT 
    CONCAT_WS('/', `listcustomers`.`name`, `listlocations`.`name`, 
`listareas`.`name`, `listassets`.`name`) AS `path`,
        `listprojects`.`name` AS `text`,
        'projects' AS `type`,
        `listprojects`.`idx` AS `id`,
        `listprojects`.`active` AS `active`,
        NULL AS `icon`
FROM
    `listprojects`
JOIN `listassets` ON `listassets`.`idx` = `listprojects`.`parentAssetId`
JOIN `listareas` ON `listareas`.`idx` = `listassets`.`parentAreaId`
JOIN `listlocations` ON `listlocations`.`idx` = 
`listareas`.`parentLocationId`
JOIN `listcustomers` ON `listcustomers`.`idx` = 
`listlocations`.`parentCustomerId`)
```

Comment: It's rarely possible to answer performance questions like this in a general way. It will depend on your table structure, indexes, etc. And which result is more useful will depend on your needs. However, it's usually best to filter in the subqueries rather than filtering after creating the big union.

Comment: Ok so there's no real standard for this then, that's what I was checking making sure I wasn't doing something egregiously wrong.

That's a good call though, I can definitely alter this to do the WHERE active clause inside with our application.